# Request location on the Apple Watch only, without code on the paired phone

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, apple-watch

I've looked everywhere including [Apple's sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PotLoc/Listings/Potloc_WatchKit_Extension_StreamLocationInterfaceController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016176-Potloc_WatchKit_Extension_StreamLocationInterfaceController_swift-DontLinkElementID_11).
But I can't find anywhere when I can request location without needing any code running on the phone, the below code when used in an 'interface controller' returns a "not determined" status.  I did check that my info.plist has the privacy key values set.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    /// Location manager to request authorization and location updates.
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    /// Flag indicating whether the manager is requesting the user's location.
    var isRequestingLocation = false

      var workoutLocation: CLLocation?

    func requestLocation() {

        guard !isRequestingLocation else {
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            isRequestingLocation = false
            return
        }

        let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        switch authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            isRequestingLocation = true
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            isRequestingLocation = true
            manager.requestLocation()

        case .denied:
            print("Location Authorization Denied")
        default:
            print("Location AUthorization Status Unknown")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard !locations.isEmpty else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let lastLocationCoordinate = locations.last!.coordinate

            print("Lat =  \(lastLocationCoordinate.latitude)")

            print("Long = \(lastLocationCoordinate.longitude)")

            self.isRequestingLocation = false

        }
    }
}
```

Main App info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We will read your location while performing a workout to create a workout route</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We will read your location while performing a workout to create a workout route</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We will read your location while performing a workout to create a workout route</string>
```

Watch Extension info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We will read your location while performing a workout to create a workout route</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We will read your location while performing a workout to create a workout route</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We will read your location while performing a workout to create a workout route</string>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am having the same situation.

Comment: @kolczak I haven't yet, tabled to come back to it.  Let me know if you figure anything out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The user can only grant access to their location on their iPhone. It cannot be done on the Apple Watch. If the iPhone to which the Watch is connected is unlocked, the prompt asking for location usage authorization will be displayed on the phone; you don't need to run any code for this on iOS.

From the [App Programming Guide for watchOS: Leveraging iOS Technologies](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/iOSSupport.html)

> Be aware that permission for some technologies must be accepted on the
>   user’s iPhone. The user must grant permission to use specific system
>   technologies, such as Core Location. Using one of these technologies
>   in your WatchKit extension triggers the appropriate prompt on the
>   user’s iPhone. Apple Watch also displays a prompt of its own, asking
>   the user to view the permission request on the iPhone. For information
>   about the technologies that require user permission, see “Supporting
>   User Privacy” in App Programming Guide for iOS.

Comment: I still think I'm missing something..I request `whenInUseStatus` on the watch, but there is no prompt that request for location prompt that pops on the iPhone?  Are you sure no code needs to run on the iPhone?

Comment: Are you sure you set up the `Info.plist` file correctly for your Watch target as well and not just for your iPhone target? Yes, even the documentation explicitly states that the prompt can be shown on the iPhone without any iOS code.

Comment: I am pretty sure, I added my info.plist values to my question.

Answer (score 10):

As of watchOS 6.0/ Xcode 11, this is now possible. To enable it, the watch extension target must have the box checked for `Supports running without iOS App installation`

After checking this setting and rebuilding, my `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` call showed the prompt on the watch face as expected.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I managed to get it working, too. But every time there's an WatchOS update, it will stop working. And for some reason asking for it again won't work, so I have to delete the app and install it again for the popup to show.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work (using Xcode 10.2.1, iOS 12.4, WatchOS 5.3), but only after adding the necessary keys (`NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`) to `Info.plist` for the iPhone app.  Initially I only had them defined in the Watch App Extension, and in that case, the request for location authorization displayed nothing on the phone. Once I added them to the iPhone Info.plist, I got the expected authorization dialog on the iPhone when requesting authorization from the Watch app, without adding any additional code to the iPhone app.

Perhaps this was a bug in previous versions, or perhaps it was the use of [deprecated versions of the key names](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocationusagedescription)?

Comment: I followed these steps but I can't see the prompt on my side (Xcode 12.3, iOS 14, WatchOS 5/6/7)... Have you been facing any issue lately? See my full question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65850886/2681506