# RequestWhenInUseAuthorization in Xamarin on WatchOS not showing any authorization request

Tags: ios, xamarin, watchos

I'm trying to use Location services on a WatchOS app in Xamarin. I have the following code in my InterfaceController.Awake() method

```
        _locationManager = new CLLocationManager();
        _locationManager.Delegate = new MyLocationDelegate(LatitudeLabel, LongitudeLabel);
        _locationManager.DesiredAccuracy = CLLocation.AccuracyBest;
        _locationManager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();
        _locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation();
```

The LocationDelegate has the following implementation of AuthorizationChanged:

```
  public override void AuthorizationChanged(CLLocationManager manager, CLAuthorizationStatus status)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Location authorization changed: {0}", status);
    }
```

When running the app in the WatchOS simulator I get the following output:

```
   2020-12-28 12:51:42.519358+0100 watchgpsWatchOSExtension[8630:441021] Location authorization changed: NotDetermined
```

I have the following key/values in all my Info.plists (WatchOS App/Extension and iOS Companion app):

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>To get locations</string>
```

According to this SO question:

[Request location on the Apple Watch only, without code on the paired phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543655/request-location-on-the-apple-watch-only-without-code-on-the-paired-phone)

I should have gotten an authorization request on the simulated iPhone, but nothing happens.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Idk about xamarin, but in Swift delegate is hold by weak reference, so it might be deallocated after assignment in your case. Try to keep strong reference somewhere

Comment: No, the delegate is working. For example, the log message I referenced above is written by the delegate. In fact, the whole app works nicely as long as I authorize it on the corresponding IOS app first. I would just like to be able to do this without running the companion app first.