# WatchKit WatchOS - Location Services Prompt never displayed on the Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-location, apple-watch, watchos

When I call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` from an Watch App, the Location Services prompt is never displayed to the user: neither in the Watch app, nor in the iPhone app.

- The *Support Running Without iOS App Installation* is not checked (if I check it, the prompt is correctly displayed, but I don't want my app to work without an iOS companion app).
- I added the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in the info.plist of both the iPhone app and the Watch Extension.
- I also tried to add the Location Services in background mode (for both the iPhone and the Watch Extension).

How can we have the prompt displayed on the Watch? Is that even possible? I don't necessarily want to ask my users to open their iPhone app to manage the request location in the app.

---

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var watchLocationManager = WatchLocManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Request location") { watchLocationManager.requestAuthorization() }
            .onAppear {
                watchLocationManager.setupLocationManager()
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
    
class WatchLocManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    func setupLocationManager() {
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.activityType = .otherNavigation
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 20.0
    }
    
    func requestAuthorization() {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}

extension WatchLocManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        print("⌚️ locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization: \(manager.authorizationStatus.rawValue)")
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print(locations)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone and Watch share Privacy>Location Services Settings. If the app already has an authorization status on the iPhone it won't ask again on the Watch.

Set the Settings>Privacy>LocationServices>YourApp>Allow Location Access>Ask Next Time.

Then open the Watch app.

**Requested Steps**

New Project>WatchOS>iOS App with WatchApp

Filled in product name, no other changes

Saved in a Mac folder

Replaced `struct ContentView` & `struct ContentView_Previews` with your code.

The `ContentView.swift` file was under the `AppName` folder.

ADDED to the above file’s `Target Membership` the `AppName WatchKit Extension`. I did this in the `File Inspector` by checking the box.

Went to the `ContentView.swift` file that was under the `AppName WatchKit Extension` folder and REMOVED (un-checking) the file’s `Target Membership` to `AppName WatchKit Extension`. (You will have a duplicate if you don’t do this)

Added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to `Info.plist` under the `AppName WatchKit Extension` Folder.

Made sure `AppName WatchKit App` scheme was selected.

Pressed Play. Waited until done loading…

Pressed the “Request Location” Button

Comment: I tried that too. Not working on my side. When I choose ask, the button does nothing.

Comment: Your code works on Simulator Xcode 12.3. Something else has to be affecting it.

Comment: I tried again in Xcode 12.3, iOS 14.3, WatchOS 7.2 & 6.2.3 & 5.3. No success on my side. From a fresh install, I launch the app, and click on the button to request access from the Watch simulator and nothing happens... Can you share what worked for you please?

Comment: See above. I added the steps I took.

Comment: For me, it started working after I activated "Supports Running Without iOS App Installation" in the WatchKit Extension General settings.

Comment: Skahlerts suggestion worked for me too.  I tried all sorts of things but did not get the prompt until I ticked the box.  WatchOS8 + iOS15